# ASP.NET Core 3.x with B2C Login - Retrieve SessionId

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to retrieve the SessionId (`sid`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set) from the Azure AD B2C authentication.

I have tried with `<User.Identity from the PageModel>.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value`; but this is null.

I have tried to add it as an optional claim in the manifest but either I get the syntax wrong or this is not the right path.

Can somebody point me in the right direction, ideally with a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v10-and-v20-optional-claims-set) that you mentioned is used for **Azure AD**, and `sid` is not available in **Azure AD B2C**. There is a similar [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1935#issuecomment-661286949).

There are [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#claims) of id token in Azure AD B2C, and sid is not in.

Comment: Thanks - is there any way of achieving the higher objective here, ie have my aspnetcore app know when a user is logged in in the same session? 
I can use the aspnetcore Session (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but that is a 'duplicate'
Alternatively the auth_time from the claim?

Comment: In Azure AD B2C we do not control the user sessions.